# Trying to fetch data from and external API but code breaks

Tags: reactjs, api, fetch-api, page-refresh, openweathermap

I'm trying to fetch data from an external API. It shows at first but when I refreshes the browser, it goes blank. The code is in my GitHub repo. thanks
https://github.com/Rengkat/weather-app.git

Answer (score 0):

The initial state of `data` is `{}`. As a consequence, `data.name` and `data.sys` are undefined, so trying to render `data.sys.country` throws an error before the app can render the input field.

```
<div className="details">
  <div className="country">
    <h3>
      {data.name}, {data.sys.country}
    </h3>
```

I recommend setting the initial state of `data` to `null` and wrapping everything other than the input field in a conditional that only allows rendering if `data` is truthy:

```
function FetchDataComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
...
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="input">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter country..."
          value={country}
          onChange={handleChange}
          onKeyPress={fetchData}
        />
      </div>
      {data ? (
        <div className="details">
          <div className="country">
            <h3>
              {data.name}, {data.sys.country}
            </h3>
          </div>
...
```

Comment: Happy to help, @Rengkat. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.